# Python Subprocess call() does not execute shell command

Tags: python, subprocess, youtube-dl

I am trying to make a python program(python 3.6) that writes commands to terminal to download a specific youtube video(using youtube-dl).

If I go on terminal and execute the following command:

```
cd; cd Desktop; youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU"
```

It will download the video to my desktop. However, if I execute the below code, which should be doing the same command on terminal, it does not throw an error but also does not download that video.

```py
import subprocess                
cmd = ["cd;", "cd", "Desktop;", "youtube-dl", "\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU\""]
print(subprocess.call(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True))
```

It seems that this just outputs 0. I do not think there is any kind of error 0 that exists(there are error 126 and 127). So if it is not throwing an error, why does it also not download the video?

Update:
I have fixed the above code by passing in a string, and have checked that youtube-dl is installed in my default python and is also in the folder where I want to download the videos, but its still throwing error 127, meaning command "youtube-dl" is not found.

Comment: if you use `shell=True` then you can use single string instead of list `cmd = "cd ; cd Desktop ; youtube-dl "\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU\""`

Comment: code 0 means "OK"

Comment: Thanks. I executed as a string, but error 127 is returned(which means command not found I believe). However, running that exact string in Terminal works, so what would the error 127 refer to? I have youtube-dl so I'm pretty sure its command should be found.

Comment: different programs may use different error's codes for different problems. You can try simpler command ie. `"cd ; ls"` and later `"cd ; cd Desktop"` to check if it can work with commands in single string. You could also use `subprocess.run()` or [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get messages displayed by commands. maybe there will be useful information about problem. Or maybe you have to use full path to `youtube-dl`. Subprocess may run with different settings then real user and it may not find `youtube-dl`.

Comment: Youtube-dl is already installed in my default python. I tried copying and pasting it into a new folder where I will download the videos, but it still returns an error 127.

Comment: better use `check_output` to see if it display any error message. It will be more usful then error 127. And try with `/full/path/to/youtube-dl`

Answer (score 0):

`cd; cd Desktop; youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU"` is not a single command; it's a *list* (delimited by `;`) of three separate commands.

`subprocess.call(cmd, ..., shell=True)` is effectively the same as

```
subprocess.call(['sh', '-c'] + cmd)
```

which is almost never what you want. Instead, just pass a single string and let the shell parse it.

```
subprocess.call('cd; cd Desktop; youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU"', shell=True)
```

If you really want to use the list form (which is always a good idea), use the `cwd` parameter instead of running `cd`.

```
subprocess.call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU'],
                cwd=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
```

Comment: I implemented the subprocess.call('cd; cd Desktop; youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b91ovTKCZGU"', shell=True) code, but now it returns an error 127, which i believes means command not found, referring to the youtube-dl command. However, executing that exact string on terminal seems to work fine, so I'm sure youtube-dl can work inside my Desktop. Any idea where the error 127 comes from?

Comment: You are probably running Python in a way that it isn't inheriting a `PATH` value that has the directory where `youtube-dl` is stored.

Comment: Youtube-dl is already installed in my default python. I tried copying and pasting it into a new folder where I will download the videos, but it still returns an error 127.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this with an example:

```
>>> subprocess.call(["echo $0 $2", "foo", "skipped", "bar"], shell=True)
foo bar
0
```

The first element of the list is the shell command (`echo $0 $2`), and the remaining elements are the positional parameters that the command can optionally use (`$0`, `$1`, ...).

In your example, you are creating a subshell that only runs the `cd;` command.  The positional parameters are ignored.  See the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and [bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) docs for details.

As noted in the comments, you should make the command a string (not a list).

Comment: Thanks, I have now passed in a string, and the commands returns error 127(command not found). I believe this is referring to the "youtube-dl" command, but running that exact string works in Terminal on my computer. Any idea what the error 127 refers to?

Comment: Are you using a Python virtual environment?  `subprocess.call` will spawn a new shell, so you might need to activate a virtual environment as part of `cmd`.  Or install `youtube-dl` in your default Python.

Comment: Youtube-dl is already installed in my default python. I tried copying and pasting it into a new folder where I will download the videos, but it still returns an error 127.

Comment: If you `cd` into a directory with `youtube-dl`, you would run it as `./youtube-dl`.